# Python - Create a subdirectory contains all directories and files in the parent directory

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, shutil, pathlib

I want to create a subdirectory contains all directories and files in the parent directory.

For example:
There exists a parent directory and its subdirectories and files.

```
/parent
    /parent/child1
        /parent/child1/a.txt
        /parent/child1/b.txt
    /parent/child2
        /parent/child2/child2-1
            /parent/child2/child2-1/c.txt
        /parent/child2/child2/d.txt
    /parent/e.txt
```

My Target: Create a subdirectory called "new" that contains all directories and files in the parent directory.:

```
/parent
    /parent/new
        /parent/new/child1
            /parent/new/child1/a.txt
            /parent/new/child1/b.txt
        /parent/new/child2
            /parent/new/child2/child2-1
                /parent/new/child2/child2-1/c.txt
            /parent/new/child2/child2/d.txt
        /parent/new/e.txt
```

Is there a Pythonic way to meet my needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shutil.copytree` is the usual way to recursively copy a directory tree to a new location, and it has options for whether to error out on existing directories, follow symlinks, and so on.

The complication, however, is that your destination is *inside* of the source, meaning that any recursive approach may end up beginning to re-copy the newly created tree as part of the source, ad infinitum.

The safest way to manage this is to copy your directory of interest to some temporary directory *outside* of it, and then copy from that intermediate location to the destination:

```py
import tempfile, shutil
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp:
    temp_new = temp + '/new'
    shutil.copytree('..', temp_new)
    shutil.copytree(temp_new, 'new')
```